# Delete Rows Older than 30 Days Using Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to delete the records from my database table that are older than 30 days. I haven't executed the code because I wanted to check if I'm doing it right.

```
App\MyTable::whereDate( 'created_at', '<=', now()->subDays( 30 ) )->delete();
```

Is that a correct way of deleting rows older than 30 days from a table? Also, what would happen if it found zero records older than 30 days, would it throw an exception error or just run gracefully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have a typo. Try

`MyTable::whereDate( 'created_at', '<=', now()->subDays(30))->delete();`

2. It would run gracefully

Comment: If I do App\MyTable::whereDate( 'created_at', '<=', now()->subDays( 30 ) )->get(); it works, do I really need to put Carbon\Carbon:: in front of now()?

Comment: no, not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
$from= Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->toDateString();

$current = Carbon::now()->toDateString();

ModelName::whereBetween('created_at', array($diff,$current))
           ->delete();
```

Hope this works perfectly! Please also let me know it works or not!

Comment: Why use toDateString()? Is it really needed?

Comment: toDateString() returns only datetime as a string.